# More comprehensive summary() function in R?

Tags: r, modeling, diagnostics

I was wondering if there was a more comprehensive summary() function in R that perhaps includes more model metrics such as confidence intervals around the estimates maybe log-likelihood, AIC, BIC stuff like that. I know it's pretty easy to just call other functions on the model object to get these metrics but it would be better if it was all packaged in the summary function.

Comment: For what kind of model? `summary()` calls object specific methods (eg, `summary.lm()`, `summary.glm()`, `summary.merMod()`, etc). You could also write your own function.

Comment: If you have an `lm` object then call `summary()` on it

Comment: Yeah but can you get confidence intervals around your parameter estimates and other model statistics from summary()

Comment: For confidence interval, use `confint()`.

Comment: Your question leaves to many things undetermined, which is why it's not a default return. For example, you do not specify which confidence intervals you want. What alpha level? Do you want a confidence interval for each element of est coefficient vector or the the confidence region for the whole vector (or a subset of it)? etc 

If you want a specific set of returned values then you can write your own summary function and print method.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily MORE comprehensive, but I tend to write my own summary functions. Then I can tailor to the particular application. I always seem to need the "n" and it is not in any available summaries.

```
sumstats<-function(x) {
  n<-NROW(x)
  mean<-mean(x)
  max<-max(x)
  min<-min (x)
  SD<- sd(x)
  hist<-hist(x)
  summary<-list(n=n,mean=mean,max=max,min=min,SD=SD)
  return(summary)
}
```

Comment: Cool thxs I did it more around a model but here is my function: summaryRobust <- function(model){
    regOutput <- cbind( as.data.frame(summary(model)[4]), as.data.frame(confint(model)) )
   colnames(regOutput) <- c("Estimate", "Std. Error", "T-Value", "P-Value", "C.I. 2.5%", "C.I. 97.5%")
   metrics <- as.data.frame(cbind(AIC(model), BIC(model), logLik(model)))
   colnames(metrics) <- c("AIC", "BIC", "logLik")
   par(mfrow=c(2,2))
   plot(model)
   list(Model_Output = regOutput, Other_Metrics = metrics)
}

Answer (score 0):

This is more of what I was hoping for in  a summary function:

```
summaryRobust <- function(model){
    regOutput <- cbind( as.data.frame(summary(model)[4]), as.data.frame(confint(model)) )
   colnames(regOutput) <- c("Estimate", "Std. Error", "T-Value", "P-Value", "C.I. 2.5%", "C.I. 97.5%")

   rSq <- summary(model)$r.squared
   Adj_rSq <- summary(model)$adj.r.squared
   modelFit <- rbind(rSq, Adj_rSq)
   rownames(modelFit) <- c("R-squared", "Adjusted R-squared")
   colnames(modelFit) <- c("")

   metrics <- as.data.frame(cbind(AIC(model), BIC(model), logLik(model)))
   colnames(metrics) <- c("AIC", "BIC", "logLik")
   rownames(metrics) <- c("")

   par(mfrow=c(2,2))
   plot(model)
   out <- list(Model_Output = regOutput, Model_Fit = modelFit, Other_Metrics = metrics)
   return(out)
}
```